# My 3D array length is 2, but accessing index 2 panics at run time

Tags: arrays, rust

I have the following code

```
fn main() {
    let mut array: [[[i32; 32]; 32]; 2] = Default::default();

    for x in 0..31 {
        for y in 0..31 {
            array[x][y][1] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it I get the error

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 2 but the index is 2', src/main.rs:6:13
```

This is the `array[x][y][1] = 1;` line.

If the array has a length of two, I should be able to put something in at index one, but for some reason, it says I'm trying to access index 2. What is the solution to this?

Comment: Dimensions are in different order. In reverse order you assume them to be.

Answer (score 4):

```
let array1: [i32; 2];
```

Is an array of 2 `i32`. Easy. Now `i32` is the type that is "inside" the array of 2. So when we write:

```
let array2: [[i32; 32]; 2];
```

This is an array of 2 `[i32; 32]` elements. So it's an array of 2 arrays of 32 `i32` elements. When you do:

```
let array: [[[i32; 32]; 32]; 2]
```

the **inner** dimension is `32`, while the most **outer** dimension is 2.

I guess you mean to:

```
let mut array: [[[i32; 2]; 32]; 32] = Default::default();

for x in 0..31 {
    for y in 0..31 {
        array[x][y][1] = 1;
    }
}
```